# Filehandle Quirk Perl

Tags: perl, file, filehandle

In the following code if there is space between `FILE` and `(` in the `printf` statement
like

```
printf FILE ("Test string inline\n");
```

Perl will treat `FILE` as a filehandle otherwise

```
printf FILE("Test string inline\n");
```

will be treated as subroutine call(If no subroutine is defined by FILE perl will through an error `Undefined subroutine &main::FILE called at ./test.pl line xx` ). Isn't there a better way Perl can implement this ? (Maybe this is why bareword filehandles are considered outdated ?)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

open(FILE,">test.txt");
printf FILE ("Test string inline\n");
close(FILE);


sub FILE
{
    return("Test string subroutine\n");
}
```

Comment: Use `print(FILE "String")` or `print FILE "String"`.

Comment: Barewords file handles are considered outdated because they refer to global variables.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It's not answerable. You go from talking about Perl syntax to asking if some unmentioned implementation could be improved with no mention of the metric against which this improvement should be measured.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to avoid that error accidentally? You could wrap the handle in curlies

```
printf({ HANDLE } $pattern, @args);
print({ HANDLE } @args);
say({ HANDLE } @args);
```

Or since parens are often omitted for `say`, `print` and `printf`,

```
printf { HANDLE } $pattern, @args;
print { HANDLE } @args;
say { HANDLE } @args;
```

Or you could use a method call

```
HANDLE->printf($pattern, @args);
HANDLE->print(@args);
HANDLE->say(@args);
```

Comment: Yes. I was trying to avoid this happening.

Comment: To prevent the error from happening, don't place the syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short );
use English qw( -no_match_vars ) ;  # Avoids regex performance penalty

my $test_file = 'test.txt';

open my $test_fh, '>', $test_file      or die "could not open $test_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
printf {$test_fh} "Test string inline" or die "could not print $test_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
close   $test_fh                       or die "could not close $test_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
```